# OpenVPN clients with same subnet in a client to client environment

Tags: openvpn

I am currently using a client-to-client function of the openvpn to establish a connection between the clients:
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/expanding-the-scope-of-the-vpn-to-include-additional-machines-on-either-the-client-or-server-subnet/

As an example, we have a setup as described below:

```
      VPN assigned IP: 10.8.0.2                                    VPN assigned IP: 10.8.0.3
             Client site                       Office                        Home
   |RUT240 router (vpn client)|<----------> |Fortigate|<---------->|User Laptop (vpn client)|
          LAN 192.168.1.0/24                    / \                          
          Device 1: 192.168.1.1                  |
          Device 2: 192.168.1.2                  |
                                                \ /
                                       |OpenVPN server on VM|  
                                          LAN IP: 10.0.0.245
                                       VPN assigned IP: 10.8.0.1
```

One of the potential issues with this setup is that we have machines with the same RUT240 configurations (although each RUT240 deployed with our machine will have its own unique key and certificate) deployed across different sites and according to the documentation, client LAN subnet (192.168.1.0/24 in our example) must not be exported to the VPN by the server or any other client sites which are using the same subnet and very subnet which is joined to the VPN via routing must be unique.

Due to the way the systems are designed, we must have the same LAN subnet address for each system and it means that we end up having multiple RUT240 routers sitting on the same subnet (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24) connected to a single server, for example multiple of the below node scattered through out the sites:
Client site
|RUT240 router (vpn client)
LAN 192.168.1.0/24
Device 1: 192.168.1.1
Device 2: 192.168.1.2

It would be greatly appreciate if you could make suggestions on ways to resolve this issue.

Comment: However you set up (Client to Site, Site to Site), the subnets at each end must be different in order for traffic to pass.

Comment: @jin167 Pick another `/24` (e.g. from the `10.0.0.0/8` block) for each of the "node" in concern and configure both source and destination NAT on the RUT240?

Comment: @Tom this is what I am trying at the moment but I had a look at openVPN cloud example setup on how to deal with this type of issue, https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/remote-access-private-networks-overlapping-ip-address/
I might give this a try and see how it works out..